# How many "ANGLES" does a pentagon have?

Tags: geometry

If asked "How many angles does a pentagon have?" would the exterior and interior angles count as 2 angles for each vertex?

Comment: The simplest answer is that a pentagon has $5$ sides, $5$ angles. By extending the sides, you could get as many as $40$ angles ($4$ per intersection of $2$ lines, $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ intersections). Pentagons with $2$ parallel sides will have $36$ angles (those $2$ lines will not intersect).

Comment: in maths, to say "angle" refeers to say "acute angle", like say "root" means "arithmetic root"

Comment: If it were ten, then by that logic there is never a lone angle anywhere. Any context in which you would measure an angle, there would be a supplementary angle too. So it just makes more practical sense to stick with the interior angles.

Comment: Why would the exterior angles count?  How many angles does a triangle have?  By my reckoning a *tri*angle has $3$ angles and not $6$.  We only count the interiors.  If mathematician respect consistancy as much as we claim we do, then the reasoning for a pentago shouldn't be any different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one can argue and justify a variety of answer but it comes down to what we *mean* when we ask the question.

I figure if we ask how many angles a pentagon has we absolutely should mean *exactly* the same thing as when we ask how many angles does any type of polygon have.

And if we ask how many angles a *tri*angle has the universally accepted answer is ... $3$.

So what do we *mean* by that?

*Presumably* we mean how many interior angles and we assume one interior angle at each vertex.

So if we mean the same thing then the answer to "how many angles does a pentagon have" *should* be $5$.

Of course, we *could* (and many of us will; we *just* can't help ourselves... we are mathematicians after all) argue that a triangle *really* has $6$ angles because we *should* count exterior angles. But such arguments are usually met with a smirk and walking away.

The answer is $5$.

Answer (score 0):

The "angles" in the question "How many angles does [some shape] has" almost always refers to the number of internal angles. So, a pentagon has $5$ angles.